# Floating Action Button Doesn't Return to Proper Place

Tags: android, android-animation, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button, snackbar

I'm using the `FloatingActionButton` in my layout with a `CoordinatorLayout`.

In my app, I have several buttons  that create `Snackbars` which properly appear and push the FAB up. When the user clicks on the FAB, it plays a *slide out* animation. When the user pressed the *back button*, the FAB slides back into view with a *slide in* animation.

The problem occurs when the user clicks on the FAB before the `Snackbar` has been dismissed: **when the user presses the *back button*, the button doesn't return to the same potion.** Instead, it sometimes slides up much higher than it should.

Here's a picture to help me explain the problem:
[image]

If the code will help let me know! Thanks!

Comment: The code will help us.

Comment: Please add your codes too as @ Christopher mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your support:design library. In earlier versions FAB was sometimes buggy.